# Is it possible to intelligently map a DTO in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If I want to create a DTO from properties on classes, all of which are mapped, can I do this without writing a regular SQL statement?

I've seen a lot of documentation on making the DTO class, as well as using it, but not much about how it gets created. I've seen SQL queries used with the Transformer, but that requires the use of magic strings.

***Edit:***

Thanks for the comments. I am aware there are multiple methods to retrieve DTOs, but I have been unable to find examples of methods that don't use SQL/HQL. Is there a reference somewhere, or is this one of those sparsely documented areas of NHibernate?

Comment: `I've seen SQL queries used with the Transformer, but that requires the use of magic strings` - This is not true you can transform HQL, SQL, Criteria, QueryOver and NH Linq into a DTO... What version of NH are you using, also when you say intelligently what do you mean?

Comment: "magic strings" does not mean what you think it means

Comment: Thank you @Rippo for the constructive feedback. The point of my question was to get clarification on what my options were. Do you have any references for doing this with Criteria / Queryover / Linq? I couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: As for @Diego , to me a magic string is anything that is not intelligently connected to what the name of the object is, and is simply a "string" that points to something. In that scenario, even an HQL query is a magic string. If I change the name of my object, all the references to it in SQL/HQL queries are dead. Thanks for responding and providing constructive information though.

Comment: OK, to the rest of the world, a "magic string" is a string constant with no explained meaning that should have been turned into a constant. Computers don't think, "intelligent" connections do not exist.

Comment: Even by your definition it is still a magic string. In `SELECT Foo.Bar...` `Foo.Bar` has no significance other than it is a string. It may coincidentally be the name of a table/column, but there is no `intelligent` connection between the two. However, something like `function (x as Foo) x.Bar)` is "intelligent" in that if I rename the `Bar` member in VS, the `x.Bar` reference will be updated, while the `SELECT Foo.Bar...` will not. Call it what you want, one is more "intelligent" than the other. And the first scenario is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your latest comment here are some examples of projecting a DTO using `QueryOver` and `Linq`

Using QueryOver:-

```
var schoolList = Session.QueryOver<lmschool>()
         .SelectList(i => i
         .Select(p => p.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
         .Select(p => p.Lat).WithAlias(() => dto.Lat)
         .Select(p => p.Lng).WithAlias(() => dto.Lng)
       )
       .Where(w => w.Lat != null && w.Lng != null)
       .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<MarkerDto>())
       .List<MarkerDto>();
```

Using the NH Linq provider:-

```
var schoolList = (from school in Session.Query<lmschool>()
        .Where(w => w.Lat != null && w.Lng != null)
      select new LmSchoolMarkerDto {
            Name = school.Name,
                    Lat = school.Lat,
                    Lng = school.Lng,
      }).ToList();
```

Source is from [my blog](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/linq-into-dto.html)
Also if you need to see how multiple joins are used the see this [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/07/queryover-with-multiple-joins-into-dto.html).

There are also lots of S.O. posts that should help you, see this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnhibernate%5D%20dto%20queryover&submit=search).

Comment: Thank you for your response. These examples are exactly what I was looking for. Coincidentally, I had seen your blog post and had been referencing it. Most of the posts I see on SO about DTOs with NHibernate are generic questions, assuming everyone already knows how to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

You could load all necessary entities and use AutoMapper to map them to DTOs more easily ?